# Are any upcoming distros offering PHP 7 by default?

Tags: distributions, php7

I am wondering if anyone is aware of any upcoming *nix distro which will be including PHP 7 as the default version without using any 3rd party repository?

Comment: how on earth is this too broad?  It's a basic question who's answer should be the name a distribution(s) which includes php 7.  That's just about as specific as you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 to 5 years in Debian as a wild guess. It did not even made to unstable. Half of the time for other distributions.

However you have unofficial repos with new versions. In Debian one of  the most known for i386 and amd64 packages is dotdeb.

https://www.dotdeb.org/about/
"Dotdeb is an extra repository providing up-to-date packages for your Debian servers"

They have PHP 7 since the 3rd of December (of 2015), and have had a pre-packaged beta since November.

https://www.dotdeb.org/2015/12/04/php-7-0-0-is-available-for-jessie/

To add the dotdeb repository, from https://www.dotdeb.org/instructions/

Edit /etc/apt/sources.list and add

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie all
```

Fetch the repository key and install it.

```
wget https://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg
sudo apt-key add dotdeb.gpg
```

Do then

```
apt-get update
```

And lastly:

```
apt-get install php7
```

In Ubuntu you also already have PPAs for it too.

https://bjornjohansen.no/upgrade-to-php7

Comment: I might need help with the grammar of the "already have" my mother tongue is getting in the way. Is it ok?

Comment: @RuiFRiberio, PHP 7 went into Debian unstable two days before you wrote your answer ;-). https://tracker.debian.org/news/729850

Comment: He is not asking which distribution has PHP 7, but which has PHP as the default version.  Simply including PHP 7 in a distribution is usually not hard; you have to backport it. Making it the default version is harder.

Comment: The question may made some sense at the time two months ago, when PHP7 was new, obviously it makes much less sense now. Things move fast.